# Why do angular velocity deviates from Keplerian value close to a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, kerr-metric

The energy-momentum conservation equation in General Relativity is expressed as $T^{\mu\nu}_{\;\;;\nu}=0$ and by projecting this equation into the space normal to the four-velocity, we obtain the corresponding radial momentum equation.

In Kerr geometry, the radial momentum equation is written as [eqn.(17) of [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/286/3/681/985437) without the viscosity and heat flux terms]
$$h_{r\mu}T^{\mu\nu}_{\;\;;\nu}=(u_ru_\mu+g_{r\mu})T^{\mu\nu}_{\;\;;\nu}=0$$
$$\implies u\frac{du}{dr}+\frac{u^2}{r\Delta}\left(a^2-r+\frac{A\gamma^2K}{r^3}\right)+\frac{A\gamma^2K}{r^6}+\left(u^2+\frac{\Delta}{r^2}\right)\frac{1}{p+\rho}\frac{dp}{dr}=0$$
where $u=u^r$ is the radial velocity and $K=\frac{(\Omega-\Omega_K^+)(\Omega-\Omega_K^-)}{\Omega_K^+\Omega_K^-}$, where $\Omega_K^+$ and $\Omega_K^-$ are Keplerian angular velocities for co-rotating and counter-rotating orbits respectively.

> In the above equation, $K$ measures the deviation of the angular
>   velocity from the Keplerian value.
>   ***Why does the angular velocity deviates from the Keplerian value?***
>
> *Is this true only for fluid motion since the equation is obtained from the equations of relativistic hydrodynamics, or can we observe
>   this deviation of angular velocity also for particle trajectories?*

Comment: What do you mean by "Keplerian value"? I normal parlance a "Keplerian orbit" would be one following the Keplerian law's. These laws do not care about spin, and therefore also not about prograde or retrograde.

Comment: By "Keplerian value" of angular velocity I mean the angular velocity of a Keplerian orbit. In accretion disks, sub-Keplerian angular velocities are required close to the black hole for accretion to occur. And yes, these laws doesn't care about spin but the location of the marginally stable orbit depends on the spin and so the spin parameter is astrophysically relevant.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be the same as the Keplerian value? It's different physics.

Comment: A pressureless fluid is just a set of particles. Set $dp/dr=0$ in your momentum equation and you get the equation for particle motion. As you then see, you don't only balance a $1/r^2$-gravity and centrifugal forces $v^2/r$, but more metric terms have appeared that need balancing. The resulting $v$ must naturally be different then.